# Error Saving Model when Key has changed by user

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6

I have a model using string as key instead of Id.

```
public class Item
{
    [Key]
    public string SerialNo { get; set; }
```

However, I am having issue saving:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(Item model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _db.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;
        _db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

I am getting the error when updating a record and changing SerialNo value:

```
Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows... Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded.
```

Comment: Where does `model` come from and what happened to it before?

Comment: @GertArnold I checked again and it looks like the error only occurs when I edit a record and change the SerialNo field.

Comment: why are you editing your primary key for that record ? if you are going to updated it, EF will not find it, keep the key and modify anything else and it should work.

Comment: @MauricioGraciaGutierrez there are reasons why a user might want to change the serial no, one is typo when it was first entered. Another one is an item got replaced by a newer model with different serial no. These are the reasons why I initially made the serial no editable.

Comment: if an inventory item got repleaced is a new row in your database with a new serial number the previous one should now have an "obsolete" status, if the user typed the serial wrong it needs to be deleted/deactivate it and create a new one. Other approach is to have a GUID as key and have SerialNo as another editable attribute. Having values that the user types as KEY is bad idea.

Comment: @MauricioGraciaGutierrez That is a really good suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> like the error only occurs when I edit a record and change the SerialNo field

You can’t update the key in EF, and you normally shouldn’t update the primary key anyway.

If you really need to you can use a raw SQL query, or delete, SaveChanges(), insert.

Comment: @david-browne-microsoft I guess I just have to not allow changes to the SerialNo field. The users should just delete the old record ang submit a new one instead.

Answer (score 2):

This error can mean some of these things:

- as error suggests, it could be that entity was modified since you take it from database (concurrency)
- it is possible that your database doesn't contain entity with that ID
- it could be that you use 2 different DBContext in your solution

These are some of things which are possible.

I wanted to leave comment but I don't have reputation to do that so I answered directly.

Comment: I am indeed editing a record when I got the error in the Edit post method and upon further investigation, it only happens when I change the SerialNo value.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
existedItem = _db.Set<Item>().FirstOrDefault( i=> i.SerialNo == model.SerialNo );
if (existedItem != null)
{           
_db.Entry(existedItem).CurrentValues.SetValues(model);
_db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: I updated my post indicating that the error happens when updating the record specifically the SerialNo field.